# Windows 8 Metro App Iframe

Tags: iframe, windows-8, google-api, microsoft-metro

I have searched and searched for an answer to this but I just can't seem to find out what i'm doing wrong. I am building a Windows 8 App that will be tying into Google's API and I am hung up on the whole iframe concept. I have followed example after example and nothing seems to work. Below is a snippet of both pages that I am trying to work with, along with the error I get. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>WinWebApp1</title>
<!-- WinJS references -->
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>
<!-- WinWebApp1 references -->
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <iframe id="Iframe" src="ms-app-web:///page.html"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>This is a test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error

```
APPHOST9624: The app can’t use script to load the ms-app-web:///page.html url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app.
```

Comment: you probably meant to use ms-appx-web

Comment: You are exactly right. That appears to have fixed the problem.. odd as I thought i had tried that. Either way thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.  It is definitely "ms-appx-web" that you want.

```
<iframe id="Iframe" src="ms-appx-web:///page.html"></iframe>
```